# Unable to create a dynamic project in Eclipse 3.6.1.

Tags: eclipse, installation, project

I am using eclipse 3.6.1. I am unable to create a dynamic web project.
When I am clicking on the menu of eclipse I don't see any choice for dynamic web project.
I think I need to install some plugins but could not find them. I don't know how to install those plugins. Can u please assist me?

Comment: you need to install eclipse foe j2ee developers . Check this link http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-ide-java-ee-developers/keplersr1

Answer (score 2):

You need the **Java EE Devleoper Tools** to create  **Dynamic Web Projects**

The following is the simplest way to install those tools:

- Go to `Help->Install New Software`.
- In the dropdown, select 'Juno - http://download.eclipse.org/releases/juno'
- Expand 'Web, XML, Java EE, and OSGI Enterprise Development'
- Check the box for 'Eclipse Java EE Developer Tools'

Once installed, you can create a `New -> Other -> Dynamic Web Project`

*A similar process exists for later versions of Eclipse, e.g. Kepler. Simply, replace Juno with your versions' code name.*

Lastly, to avoid the install using your current Eclipse, you can download Eclipse prepackaged with JEE Developer Tools. The latest (current) version of `Eclipse with JEE Developer Tools` is available [here](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-ide-java-ee-developers/keplersr1). Or, ff you really need `Eclipse 3.6.x with JEE Developer Tools`, you can get that [here](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/release/helios/sr2)

Comment: I have tried the above process. But when i am trying to download it is showing the error msg as An internal error occurred during: "Install download1".
Comparison method violates its general contract!

Comment: You can download Eclipse 3.6.x for JEE here. This will have the Java EE Web tools installed by default http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/release/helios/sr2

Comment: Great news! Please consider accepting my answer if it satisfies you answer. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Install [Eclipse for Java EE](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-ide-java-ee-developers/keplersr1) developers and check out [Dynamic Web Projects](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.wst.webtools.doc.user%2Ftopics%2Fccwebprj.html).

To create a new dynamic Web project, complete the following steps:

```
Open the Java EE perspective.
In the Project Explorer, right click on Dynamic Web Projects, and select New > Dynamic Web         
Project from the context menu. The New Dynamic Web Project wizard starts.
Follow the project wizard prompts.
```